# pgAdmin4: Instance '<Server at 0x1f19e9854c0>' is not persisted

Tags: pgadmin-4, windows-11

I have used pgAdmin v3 and v4 to access my dB without any problem.
However, after deleted all the connection list and add new server or server group, I got this error:

"Instance '<Server at 0x1f19e9854c0>' is not persisted"

This occurs only at pgAdmin4 and pgAdmin3 still works fine.

System: Windows 11
postgreSQL Server installed at Ubuntu(64-bit), VirtualBox
Server Version: PostgresSQL 9.3.16

pgAdmin version: pgAdmin3 1.22.2; pgAdmin4 4.29